# How to fix deprecation notices in Symfony 5 when using PHPUnit with Phake?

Tags: symfony, phpunit, phake

I develop my app with Symfony 5 and test it with PHPUnit, along with Phake to mock my classes. I've just updated Symfony from 5.2 to 5.3, including symfony/phpunit-bridge as well as the recipes. In `symfony.lock`, phpunit jumped from version 4.7 to 9.3 (in `composer.json` version is ^9.5).

Now, I have the following messages when I run my tests (I didn't have them before):

```sh
Remaining indirect deprecation notices (3)

  1x: The "Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Mime\TemplatedEmail::__serialize()" method is considered internal. It may change without further notice. You should not extend it from "TemplatedEmail_PHAKEcbeb592e8143b41".
    1x in ContactMailerTest::testSendEmail from App\Tests\Mailer

  1x: The "Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Mime\TemplatedEmail::__unserialize()" method is considered internal. It may change without further notice. You should not extend it from "TemplatedEmail_PHAKEcbeb592e8143b41".
    1x in ContactMailerTest::testSendEmail from App\Tests\Mailer

  1x: Class "TranslatorInterface_PHAKEe9b1bfdc40995c1" should implement method "Symfony\Contracts\Translation\TranslatorInterface::getLocale()": Returns the default locale.
    1x in EmailFactoryTest::testCreateEmail from App\Tests\Mailer
```

It seems to me that the deprecation comes from the fact that Phake is mocking the classes and thus extending from the classes without implementing a method when it should, and implementing them when it shouldn't.

So I'm guessing that it's not actually my code that is deprecated. Am I right?

If so, how could I fix these deprecations without disabling them?
Is that a symfony/phpunit-bridge problem, a PHPUnit problem, or a Phake problem?

---

**Edit:** Since I got a -1 without a comment to tell me what is wrong with my post, I'll try to add some precisions.

I have made some research prior to posting this question: I haven't found anything related to this type of deprecation notices and Phake.

I *know* that my code doesn't contain deprecations because I don't have any deprecation notices other than these.

Here's my code from ContactMailerTest if that can help:

```php
final class ContactMailerTest extends TestCase
{
    private MailerInterface $mailer;
    private EmailFactory $factory;
    private LoggerInterface $logger;
    private ContactMailer $contactMailer;
    private Contact $contact;
    private TemplatedEmail $email;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->mailer = Phake::mock(MailerInterface::class);
        $this->factory = Phake::mock(EmailFactory::class);
        $this->logger = Phake::mock(LoggerInterface::class);
        $this->contact = Phake::mock(Contact::class);
        $this->contact->name = 'Jane';
        $this->contact->emailAddress = 'jane@example.com';
        $this->contact->message = 'Cat ipsum dolor sit amet !';
        $this->email = Phake::mock(TemplatedEmail::class);

        Phake::when($this->factory)->createEmail($this->contact->name, $this->contact->emailAddress, $this->contact->message)->thenReturn($this->email);

        $this->contactMailer = new ContactMailer($this->mailer, $this->factory, $this->logger);
    }

    public function testSendEmail(): void
    {
        $this->contactMailer->sendEmail($this->contact);

        Phake::verify($this->factory)->createEmail('Jane', 'jane@example.com', 'Cat ipsum dolor sit amet !');
        Phake::verify($this->mailer)->send($this->email);
        $this->assertTrue($this->contactMailer->hadSuccess);
    }
}
```

and from EmailFactoryTest:

```php
final class EmailFactoryTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testCreateEmail(): void
    {
        $translator = Phake::mock(TranslatorInterface::class);
        $name = 'Jane';
        $emailAddress = 'jane@example.com';
        $message = 'Cat ipsum dolor sit amet !';

        Phake::when($translator)->trans('email.contact.address')->thenReturn('contact@example.com');
        Phake::when($translator)->trans('email.contact.name')->thenReturn('Contact');
        Phake::when($translator)->trans('email.chloe.address')->thenReturn('chloe@example.com');
        Phake::when($translator)->trans('email.chloe.name')->thenReturn('Chloé');
        Phake::when($translator)->trans('email.contact.subject', ['name' => $name])->thenReturn('Message de la part de '.$name);

        $factory = new EmailFactory($translator);
        $email = $factory->createEmail($name, $emailAddress, $message);

        $from = $email->getFrom()[0];
        $this->assertEquals('contact@example.com', $from->getAddress());
        $this->assertEquals('Contact', $from->getName());

        $to = $email->getTo()[0];
        $this->assertEquals('chloe@example.com', $to->getAddress());
        $this->assertEquals('Chloé', $to->getName());

        $replyTo = $email->getReplyTo()[0];
        $this->assertEquals('jane@example.com', $replyTo->getAddress());
        $this->assertEquals('Jane', $replyTo->getName());

        $this->assertEquals('Message de la part de Jane', $email->getSubject());
        $this->assertEquals(['message' => 'Cat ipsum dolor sit amet !'], $email->getContext());
        $this->assertNotNull($email->getHtmlTemplate());
    }
}
```

---

**Edit 2:** I have symfony/phpunit-bridge package installed.

---

**Edit 3:** I've posted an issue on phake/phake repository right there: https://github.com/phake/phake/issues/300

Comment: Symfony has a package that is dedicated in handling deprecation notices within phpunit - maybe it fits for your case? https://github.com/symfony/phpunit-bridge

Comment: Actually I'm already using it :) I'll edit my post to precise that!

Comment: gotcha, now seeing you wrote it already that you're running it, my fault. Could it be that phake copies over @internal docblock tags when creating the mocks? Perhaps there is away to control that if that is. I'm not entirely prominent with Phake, so there might be some legwork.

Comment: No problem! That's my guess... I'll open an issue on the Phake repository and see what I'm told

Comment: Leave a link here to the issue, this should be of benefit. And I'm also interested if it's not possible. The warning messages are somewhat correct, perhaps the mocks should not extend these and then the warning goes away, which would be a sign that the mocks are now more correct. However one could see the mocks to be correct _anyway_ because they are mocks. Perhaps it's good to have some warnings, but maybe Symfony also has some filtering under the hood that could be applied if considered correct for mocks. Questions over questions ;)

Comment: Yeah indeed, that brings interesting questions! Here's the issue: https://github.com/phake/phake/issues/300

Comment: And already a PR upstream for Symfony:  https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/41776 - like to see that.

Comment: And approuved, and merged, I'm impressed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem was actually a Symfony problem and has been resolved in [this PR](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/41776). Updating Symfony to the latest minor version when it is released will fix the issue.